# .xcodeproj not added with git add . command

Tags: git, xcode4

I really new to this git and trying to get it work with xcode4. I have an existing xcode proj and this is what I do.

1. navigate to project dir
2. git init
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "...."

but I can't see project_name.xcodeproj in my git status. What did I do wrong about this ?

Comment: When your at the root of your git repository, what's the output of `cat .gitignore`? And also `cat ~/.gitignore`?

Comment: Your answer remind me that once upon a time I have set up global .gitignore at my root folder and when I open up that file it contain

.DS_Store
*.swp
*~.nib

build/

*.pbxuser
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3

*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3

xcuserdata

// I should delete this two line right ?
*.xcodeproj/
!*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will put answer of @Alex here in case someone would benefit from this. If some files of your project not added with git add command, looking for your **.gitignore** file in your root of your git repository, in my case its [**global .gitignore**](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/) that cause the problem.